# How to number duplicate values?

Tags: excel

I have the following data format in Excel

```
40716042
40716042
40716042
40717303
40717303
40717497
40717497
40718176
40718176
```

What i would like to do is to number duplicat value subsequently, so that eveytime the value changes the numbering will start from 1. That is the desired outcome:

```
40716042    1
40716042    2
40716042    3
40717303    1
40717303    2
...
```

Comment: try: `=COUNTIF($A$2:$A2,A2)`, the logic here is, leave the `2` part in `A2` not fixed, so it will be `A2:Ax` where x is the row number, so it will cover bigger range when you copy the function down the column, cover the previous duplicates, so increate the count

Comment: Will the data always be sorted as you show?  Or could there be a duplicate further down the column.

Answer (score 1):

See formula in formula bar and copy it down

[image]